# Configure DNS to reach AWS hosted .com webpage via a .de-domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I try to host a static webpage at Amazon AWS. To do that I want to configure DNS, such that my webpage becomes avaiable via `example.de`.

So I got to the point where the page is online via something like: `https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/example.de/index.html`

The tutorial ([docs.aws.amazon.com/..](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-update-ns-record)) recommends to use route 53 and I end up creating a DNS zone. With 4 nameserver:

```
ns-1718.awsdns-22.co.uk.
ns-1510.awsdns-60.org.
ns-319.awsdns-39.com.
ns-984.awsdns-59.net.
```

Now my problem is that the place ([Strato](http://strato.com)) where I registered the domain doesn't accept those NS. I ended up with an error that the given nameservers are not responsible for the domain.

Is that because it's a .de-domain and the nameservers are responsible for co.uk. org. com. and net.? How to resolve that or generally how to configure DNS properly here?
[image]

Comment: Did you create a hosted zone for your example.de in AWS? R53 allows .de on its NS if you create the zone and use the recommended NS from the zone you create.

Comment: I did, and got the NS mentioned above. The problem is that the registrar doesn't accept those NS.

Comment: There is no reason why this should not work... but you don't want to change your NS *records*, if that is what you are trying to do -- you need to change the authoritative nameservers for the domain.  Can you show a screenshot of what you're trying, including the error?

Comment: This is strange. Maybe try to remove trailing dots?

Comment: I added a screenshot. Sorry, there is no option to change it to english. So I'm at the registrars webpage trying to change the NS-Records. The error in the first line says: "The given nameserver is not responsible for this domain".

Comment: @DusanBajic No, that didn't work. Is it possible that it takes time to have these nameservers being responsible, such that the registrar will accept them?

Comment: I found the problem. I missed to add an A record at the amazon hosted zone. So now the nameserver were accepted.